# How to find Unitprice*Qty of all documents

Tags: mongodb

Let's say that such a document belongs to a collection called Purchase:

[image: collection]

I'm a noobie at MongoDB, I know about it's JSON structure but zero about querying

Comment: You could have used text instead of picture, really.

Comment: Search "mongodb aggregation pipeline"

Comment: are you using a language for to extract this information??

Comment: You can do an [Aggregation query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation/) on the collection using a [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage and the [multiply](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/index.html) operator.